# Ajuda em mostrar dados salvos em um banco de dados em uma página php

Tags: php, html, sql

Então galera, estou começando agora a aprender a mexer com php e estou tentando fazer um sistema de cadastro cujo será cadastro nele atividade. Já consegui muita coisa, consegui ligar o banco, consegui salvar dados no phpmyadmin através de um form. Porém, quando quero mostrar para o usuário os dados registrados em uma tabela numa página web, ele não mostra, mesmo os dados estando salvos no banco. Alguém pode me ajudar? Ficarei agradecido ;-; `

```
    <title>Sistema de Registro de Atividades</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Sistema de Registro de Atividades</h1>

    <p><a href="form-add.php">Adicionar atividade</a></p>

    <h2>Lista de atividades</h2>

    <p>Total de de atividades: <?php echo $total ?></p>

    <?php if ($total > 0): ?>

    <table width="50%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome da Atividade</th>
                <th>duracao</th>
                <th>descricao</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ($user = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $user['atividade_nome'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['duracao'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['descricao'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="form-edit.php?id=<?php echo $user['id'] ?>">Editar</a>
                    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $user['id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja remover esta atividade?');">Remover</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php else: ?>

    <p>Nenhum usuário registrado</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

`

Comment: onde você está fazendo o select no banco de dados? você precisa disso antes de chamar o método ->fetchall, e onde vc está declarando a variavel $stmt?

Answer (score 1):

Essa função em `$user = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` pelo nome parece retornar um array associativo com todos os resultados, para esta função funcionar como tu espera com uma atribuição para $user dentro do while, a função `fetchall` deveria retornar apenas um resultado por vez (uma linha da tua tabela do banco), e quando acabar retornar um false.

Se ela retorna todos como o nome parece dizer, tu deveria atribuir o resultado dela para uma variável e iterar sobre ela depois, tipo isso:

```
<?php $users = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user['atividade_nome'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['duracao'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['descricao'] ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="form-edit.php?id=<?php echo $user['id'] ?>">Editar</a>
            <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $user['id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja remover esta atividade?');">Remover</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Tu está usando alguma biblioteca de acesso ao banco ou tu que criou essa classe que tu chamou o `$stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`?